# I have 2 columns. I want to adjust one to the content and the other to take the remaining space

Tags: css

I decided to include this question in the CSS category since this works similar to the bootstrap grid.

I'm managing the ionic framework using its grid.I want to make a responsive system
.I want the first column to take the remaining space, and column 2 to be the exact size according to its content. for what? I want to make it possible to optimize the space on small screen mobile devices.

for example in small resolutions:

[image]

for example in large resolutions:

[image]

this is my code:

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-10 style="border:red 1px solid;">
        <h4 >
          <strong>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum nisi,     eos animi accusamus saepe magnam ducimus ipsa ut non, laborum reiciendis facilis reprehenderit rerum ratione praesentium. Harum, odio. Odit, dolore.

          </strong>
          <span>
          </span>
        </h4>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-auto style="border:red 1px solid;">
        <span>
            <ion-badge>Validado</ion-badge>
            <br>

            <ion-badge>No Validado</ion-badge>
        </span>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wdofnx?file=pages/home/home.html

How can fix it? thanks

Comment: Please check this link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp

Comment: @NewUser Thank you. I have read, but specifically I do not know how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
    .container {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .col {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background:red">
      <div class="col">
        <h4 >
          <strong>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum nisi,     eos animi accusamus saepe magnam ducimus ipsa ut non, laborum reiciendis facilis reprehenderit rerum ratione praesentium. Harum, odio. Odit, dolore.
          </strong>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="col" style="background:yellow">
         <h4 >
          <strong>
                        test
          </strong>
        </h4>
      </div>
      </div>
```